# Change image attributes inside textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the TinyMCE WYSIWYG text editor. The `textarea` for the text editor is called `.seo_textarea` after I hit submit I want all the images inside the `textarea` to have different `data` attributes. My logic is as follows:

```
  $('.social_properties_form').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();

            imgOptimize();

                $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '',
                  data: new FormData(this),
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  success: function(data) {
                 window.location = "/profiles/articles.php";
                  }
                });
                }
        })

function imgOptimize(){
    $(".seo_textarea img").each(function(){
        var original = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).attr('src', '/media/assets/loading-background.jpg');

        $(this).attr('data-src', original);

        var fileName = original.split('/').pop();

        $(this).attr('data-mobile-src', '/stories/media/images/mobile/' + fileName);
    });
}
```

Upon submission using Ajax to relay the information to PHP, a new row is inserted with the textarea's values. However, the textarea does not include extra data attributes for images. Instead, the original src is shown and nothing is changed.

How can I make it so that inside my database table I get the new data attributes and the changed src?

Comment: You appear to be looking through `.textContents` not `.seo_textarea`. Is this a typo? or is that a valid html element on your page?

Comment: To help facilitate an answer can you narrow down where in the sequence the problem is?... Have you determined whether imgOptimize itself is working (i.e., if you skip the AJAX call, do the images get their data attributes)? If so I think you'll need to get the TinyMCE content separately (e.g., capture tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'} and append to AJAX payload) or perhaps just call AJAX on a new thread (e.g., setTimeout(doAjaxStuff, 0)) as the DOM may not have updated yet otherwise.

Comment: @haxxxton Sorry you're right. It's a typo. I fixed it, thanks

Comment: @Synexis imgOptimize works for outside elements, like for example if we have a div and an image inside that div: e.g: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWVpbj For the textarea, however, I don't think it's working

Comment: My guess is that `.seo_textarea" has been replaced by tinyMCE (e.g., with an iFrame, although that depends on your settings), so the jQuery selector in imgOptimize doesn't actually select anything. There are a number of possible approaches using the tinyMCE API, but I implemented basic concepts of selecting the new editor and then capturing its contents at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pegVMP/ -- does that help?

Comment: @Synexis It does give the images data attributes, but the src is still the original image path and the other data attributes are the file path of the loading-background.jpg

Comment: @user2896120 tinyMCE can seem to have a mind of its own especially with images... Indeed I see src was not updated, although the data attrs. seem correct (data-src was the orig. source and data-mobile-src the mobile URL). Regardless, I revised the script (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gmrrQw/) to act on the raw HTML itself, rather than the DOM in order to prevent tinyMCE from generating its own HTML using incorrect references (alternatively, you could also just set the 'data-mce-src' attr. in addition to src, or use the tinyMCE API [e.g., notify it of change or use its image upload event]).

Comment: @Synexis I think it may be easier if I gave you the reason of why I want to do this. I'm trying to create lazy loading with the images by assigning data attributes. Also, based on screen size I either use the smaller image (data-mobile-src) or the larger image (data-src) Do you know a better way of implementing this with TinyMCE or if you know any plugins or something like that?